# What is the best way to upload a file/photo from an iOS device?

Tags: ios, security, swift3, icloud, nsfilemanager

Here's the scenario: My application features an account system, wherein users may login/logout the app, thus enabling other users to login as well using the same iOS device. Upon successful login, it downloads the files (like pdf, ppt, and etc) from the website and I put those in the app's local directory (the files are separated in folders named with the `user_id` of each user). Thus, if a user will upload a file using the app, from which directory should I get the file?

Get the file/photo from:

- A) Local file app directory (**Cons:** ability to view other user's directory)
- B) iCloud documents (**Cons:** I'm not sure if this is how generally iOS users use to store, or how about the files that isn't placed in the iCloud?)
- C) Local file app directory and restrict the folders that doesn't match with the `user_id` (Is this possible)
- D) Others

Comment: " if a user will upload a file using the app" : You mean u upload it to your server/website and keep the copy of the file locally as well ??

Comment: I just want to upload a file coming from an iOS device, which means it may be located in Photos, iCloud, or in other places that people can save their files into

Comment: I'm unsure how iphone users store their downloaded documents. iOS doesn't feature a File Manager (like in Android) but I'm aware that each app in iOS is sandboxed

Answer (score 1):

This is how upload normally works in iOS.

You will copy the file you want to upload to the application's temp directory and then create a upload task using background session configuration and pass the file path (temp folder path) to the upload task.

**Why should I pass file path ??**

If you are using background session with upload task, the current design of background session restricts you to provide the file path to task which means you can't neither stream or pass binary to upload task (by pass binary I mean you can't save file data in any variable)

**Why should I use background session??**

If you want the app to continue upload even if user puts the app to background or even kills the app (once upload task started) then background session is your only chance :)

**Why should I Copy file to temp directory only ??**

Files copied in temp directory will remain in directory temporarily as soon as you quit the app file will be deleted and files in temp directory are not backed up by iCloud :) where as files in document directory or other directory will be backed up by iCloud.

**Summary :**

1. Once user selects the file, copy it (if locally available like photo gallery) or download it (if file is saved in cloud) to temp directory of your app.
2. Create a upload task with a background session and pass file path to task :)
3. Get a cup of tea/coffee and start debugging to fix issue :)

Comment: Hi thanks! But ***where*** should I get the file? From local directory, or iCloud documents?

Comment: For example I downloaded a pdf from another website (using the app web browser), storing it to my iOS device, how would my app retrieve this file then?

Comment: If user picks the image in photo gallery and u will copy the image from photo gallery to temp directory of your app sandbox. If your app downloaded pdf file as u specified in comments above, you know where have u saved that file like in doc directory of ur app now copy that file and put it in temp folder of your app via code